# How to find the longest sequence of colors in C#

Tags: c#, linq, logic, sequence

How to calculate Longest Sequence of two Colours from last 5 colors in the following (using C#)?

```
var colorValues = new []{"Blue", "Yellow","Black","Yellow",
                         "Green","Yellow", "Yellow","Red"}
```

In the above expected sequence is "Yellow","Green","Yellow","Yellow".

Comment: You can use an algorithm based on the one developed by Jay Kadane to solve the [Maximum subarray problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem)

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks for the quick reply, do you any example in c#?

Comment: No, I don't have a c# implementation at hand, but this is not a very hard algorithm to implement, and you can probably find it implemented in c# on the web somewhere.

Comment: Any specific reason for selecting `Green` and rejecting `Black` in the given example, even though they are of same length?

Comment: @un-lucky they are not the same length. black is 3 and green is 4.

Comment: @un-lucky need to find only longest 2 color sequence.

Comment: @ZoharPeled : how you calculated `3` for Black and `4` for Green

Comment: @un-lucky: "Yellow","Black","Yellow" is 3, while "Yellow","Green","Yellow", "Yellow" is 4.

Comment: @ZoharPeled you are right

Comment: @ZoharPeled: thanks, I was confused

Comment: OP and **up-voters** perhaps should refresh them-selves with [ask] for a question that is arguably a _set of requirements_ or _homework_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var colorValues = new[]
{
    "Blue", "Yellow", "Black", "Yellow",
    "Green", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Red"
};

var query =
    from n in Enumerable.Range(0, colorValues.Length)
    from l in Enumerable.Range(1, colorValues.Length - n)
    let subseq = colorValues.Skip(n).Take(l).ToArray()
    where subseq.Distinct().Count() == 2
    orderby subseq.Count() descending
    select subseq;

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", query.First()));
```

It gives:

> Yellow, Green, Yellow, Yellow